# I'm afraid of rebooting after apt-get upgrade... [ubuntu 16.04 LTS]

Tags: apt, upgrade, raid

I made sudo apt-get update and then upgrade...

After finishing the last lines said:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-130-generic
W: mdadm: the array /dev/md/imsm0 with UUID metadata=imsm
W: mdadm: is currently active, but it is not listed in mdadm.conf. if
W: mdadm: it is needed for boot, then YOUR SYSTEM IS NOW UNBOOTABLE!
W: mdadm: please inspect the output of /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf, compare
W: mdadm: it to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, and make the necessary changes.
```

I unerstand there is something about boot drive, but I'maffraid to reboot now.
I have a RAID0 with lots of data from music production not backed up yet...

After some readings I know mdam is RAID utility and it's concerning imsm0 what apparently is sdc&sdb, so no concerning the boot drive.

But will my RAID still be alive?

Why this message?

Could someone help me ?
Thanks'!

Thanks!

Comment: Just do what the text says. Or at least update your question with the content of the two files mentioned.

Comment: Thanks (: all went ine by the way... I'm a bit late!